# Hide a div on a specific page (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to hide a div on all pages that is in my header.php file, apart from on one page i wont it to show

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href == "http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/") { 
        document.getElementById("top").style.display="block";
    }
    else {
     document.getElementById("top").style.display="none";
    }
});
</script>
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: check what is the value of `window.location.href`... add an alert/console logging like `console.log(window.location.href)` and see what is printed

Comment: It's printing the correct domain that i have been using

Comment: Also, since you are already using jQuery, you can hide the element using `$('#top').hide()` and `$('#top').show()` to show it.

Comment: still doesn't work when I use that syntax leo, no errors either.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Paste here what your console is logging **exactly** when you do `console.log(window.location.herf)`, please.

Comment: also log `console.log(window.location.href == "http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/")`

Comment: post the html that you are trying to hide, is the javascript actually running on the page in question

Comment: http://emilyandsamuel.com/shop/
(index):83 false

Comment: Clearly it is different than the url you expect

Comment: it brings the url im using then says false for the second console log Arun told me to use

Comment: weird when it logs the url on the first console log, i'll try some variations

Comment: Probably it happens because you're putting `www`, for example, and the URL doesn't have the `www`. You should be using `location.pathname` and compare it to both `/shop/` and `/shop` strings. It should work.

Comment: It was the www.  -.-

Comment: I feel like an idiot haha

Answer (score 0):

My url wasn't correct, mine doesn't have the www.

if anyone else has a similar problem use a console log to check what your url is

```
console.log(window.location.href)
```

and use a console log to check if your url is correct

```
console.log(window.location.href == "http://www.url.com")
```